# Two-port circuit analysis. Voltage gain

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: Original circuit]

[image]

I am trying to find the general equations for the voltage gain(Not sure if it is the write word for it). My textbook offers an derived equation but not the procedure. I would appreciate it if someone could show me how this is derived.(zxx are the z-parameters of the "some circuit" circuit)
$$
Hv(j\omega )= \frac{U_{2}}{U_{0}} = \frac{z_{21}(Z_{g}+Z_{b})}{(Z_{g}+z_{11})(Z_{b}+z_{22})-z_{12}z_{21})}
$$

EDIT: The upper picture is the original circuit. To this circuit we add another circuit. The equation above gives the ratio of the new voltage on the load(U2) to the original voltage on the load(U0).

Comment: Do we assume U1 = U0 ? also from where come this transfer function? Please precise your question.

Comment: Too many undefined and unexplained variables.  You haven't even defined exactly from where to where you are trying to find the voltage gain.  And what "transducer"?  We do engineering here, where such sloppiness is not tolerated.

Comment: We do not assume U1=U0. We are trying to find the ratio between the two voltages on the load. U0 is before adding the circuit, U2 is after we add some circuit. As to transducer, I am sorry about that I am not to familiar with english engineering terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e84/lectures/ch2/node4.html) you should find your answer at the half of the page, where is an example which is identically to yours. If you solve it analytically how it is shown there with the same equations and derivate the transfer function U2/U0, then you should have your answer.

This is how you solve it:
$$
1: U_1 = Z_{11}I_1+Z_{12}I_2\\
2: U_2 = Z_{21}I_1+Z_{22}I_2
$$
with equations:

$$ 3: U_1= U_0-Z_gI_1\\4:I_2=-\frac{U_2}{Z_b}$$
Insert eq. 3 and eq. 4 to eq. 1 and eq. 2 afterwards solve eq. 1 to \$I_1\$ and insert it to eq. 2. You can now solve the transfer function \$ H= \frac{U_2}{U_1}=\dots \$

Cheers

Comment: @Jure Vreča Please consider to mark the answer as correct if the answer suits your need.

Comment: Did not know I had to do that. Done now.